# Something went wrong with my drive and it won't boot Ubuntu anymore. How do I fix this?

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I was using Windows for a bit because I'm still seeing up all the programs on it following a hard drive failure. One thing Seagate said to do was run SeaTools. When I did, it didn't really say which drive was which (I have two, a 1TB with Win7 and a 250GB for Ubuntu) So I ran the smallest scan on both drives. I haven't done anything else with that tool. Then I restarted, trying to get back to Ubuntu. But it fails to boot. It says something like disk error.

I have the install disk for both OSes. What can I do to repair my Ubuntu install? I ran boot repair from a live disk. Result is here : http://paste.ubuntu.com/8169843/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this, it looks as though your 250GB hard drive has failed:

> `File descriptor 9 (/proc/12881/mounts) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 20834: bash
>   File descriptor 63 (pipe:[82571]) leaked on lvscan invocation. Parent PID 20834: bash
>     /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 250059227136: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 250059341824: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 228585308160: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 228585365504: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb1: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 21471625216: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 21471682560: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 0: Input/output error
>     /dev/sdb5: read failed after 0 of 4096 at 4096: Input/output error`

You will want to recover any files you can using a live disc, then replace the hard drive.  After you reinstall Ubuntu, you can restore the remaining files from your latest backup.

Good luck.

Comment: That's not possible, it can't just fail like that because of a scan. And there wasn't any bad sectors, either. I checked with the live disk by using fsck and disk manager. Is there anything else it could be? I can't remember off the top of my head, but it might not have been a seagate drive. Would using seagate tools mess up a non seagate drive like that?

Comment: That's true--a scan wouldn't per se cause it to fail.  But bad sectors is only a single type of failure.  I/O errors could just mean the hard drive isn't responding.  I don't know what Seagate tools do.  If it's just a SMART scan like most diagnostics, it should've been fine.

Comment: Then what would I do to figure it out?

Comment: Never mind. Apparently running it a third time or a fsck or checking for bad sectors did it. At least it works now, even though I have no idea how.

Comment: Glad you found the problem; sorry it was the drive.  Get off the failing drive as soon as possible (it can permanently fail without notice) and you should otherwise be all set.

Comment: Oddly enough, I checked again and it isn't the drive, but a failure of grub that made it not read the drive. I fixed grub and it all works great now, with no errors of either hardware or software.